# using php curl to extract data from a website with multiple submits

Tags: php, html, curl, extract

I have to extract data from a website via multiple submits and this has to be done automatically... the flow is as follows...

1. Go to this page...http://www.licindia.in/premium_calculator.htm.
2. Select something and then submit it. This will take me to a form
3. Fill up the form there and submit it...
4. get the html that is produced. and extract data.

I have used curl earlier to log into websites remotely but I cant seem to get this working anyway.

```
$url="http://www.licindia.in/premium_calculator.htm";
$postdata = "thepostdata"
$cookie = "cookie.txt" ;
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,false); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Something like this i have tried...this is not the actual thing..but this is similar

Comment: m really sorry coz i cant post the code right now as i have tried it at home. now m at workplace..but yeah..i wrote a script that declares the sbumit url and the form data needed for the form to submit. and i then allowed redirection in curl so that it gives me the new page.

Comment: You forgot your script home? ohhh ... and you cannot remake it?

Comment: well yeah.. i can make it but it will take time..as you can see if you check the url that their forms are so full of javascripts and they submit using javascript plus the form data that needs to be prepared before executing curl is gonna be complex coz of their structure.. thats it..plus there is a matter of session

Comment: you you think it wouldn't take time for anyone here?

Comment: have i ever said that?? No!! I know it would take time..i never posted gotta catch a train...check the edit..i have done something like that...

Comment: Guys, it's the summer of love http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/

Comment: @praveen ok, what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think your first issue is that the form on the page you linked is actually loaded from an `iframe`.

You will want to use that `iframe`'s url instead since cURL will not load the `iframe` srouce from the parent page.

Comment: thanks for the information. i overlooked that. but now if you have seen the page and the iframe section, can you tell me if it is a feasible option to get data from there using curl?? there is the jsession id...along with a hidden field that contains another encrypted data i dont know about.